# Netlify Redirect or Rewrite for Gatsby Wildcard Path

Tags: reactjs, redirect, url-rewriting, gatsby, netlify

So I've already implemented a wildcard path on my `gatsby-node.js` file:

```js
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  if (page.path.match(/^\/my-path/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/my-path/*"
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

and this works fine when I am running the site locally (in development). i.e., if i provide `/my-path/anything123` or `/my-path/asdfasdfasdf`, both will lead to a rendering of the component I've created in my Gatsby project under `pages/my-path.tsx`.

Now we come to my problem. When I deploy my site to Netlify, I don't get the same behavior as in development. Can behavior like this be handled with a redirect or rewrite in Netlify? I don't want to *lose* the content in what comes after `/my-path/`, as in reality I'm using it to parse an id, i.e. if the URL in the browser is `/my-path/123`, I want to be able to see that `123` in `window.location.href`, and parse it with some logic in `my-path.tsx`.

I hope this is clear. Appreciate anyone who can help or guide me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course after writing this all up the answer becomes clear... I tried it, and it works! for the example I was providing, the following redirect would work in your `netlify.toml` file:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/my-path/*"
  to = "/my-path"
  status = 200
  force = true
```

So it essentially has to match 1:1 with the rules you define in `gatsby-node.js`.